# How to make a rectangle mask with css

Tags: html, css

I have been trying for hours to make a rectangled feather around and image. I got linked to a doc for masking and clipping. I think i might be able to use this, but i cant figure out why the rectangle mask isnt working. I post the code im trying to use underneeth, thanks for any comments in advance!

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="170" height="200">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"/>
    </filter>
    <mask id="mask">
      <rectangle x="0" y="0" height="100px" width="100px" fill="white"       filter="url(#filter)"></rectangle>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  
  <image class="test" xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/Harry-Potter-1-.jpg" width="170" height="200" mask="url(#mask)"></image>
</svg>
```

Just to mention, i got this to work with the ellipse tagg!

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="170" height="200">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"/>
    </filter>
    <mask id="mask">
      <ellipse cx="50%" cy="50%" rx="60" ry="100" fill="white" filter="url(#filter)"></ellipse>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  
  <image class="test" xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/Harry-Potter-1-.jpg" width="170" height="200" mask="url(#mask)"></image>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tag should be `rect` not `rectangle`. `<rect...></rect>`

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="170" height="200">
  <defs>
    <filter id="filter">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="5"/>
    </filter>
    <mask id="mask">
    <rect x="35" y="20" height="130px" width="100px" fill="white" filter="url(#filter)"></rect>
    </mask>
  </defs>
  
  <image class="test" xlink:href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/3/Harry-Potter-1-.jpg" width="170" height="200" mask="url(#mask)"></image>
</svg>
```

Comment: Super! Thanks alot, i do have another question then, is it posible to crop it to this selection so the webpage only display the 100px in use? I wanna push alot of images close to eachother too!

Comment: No clue. I just googled stuff from your question. You might want to ask another question.